# How can docker-compose access outside window files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana-loki, promtail

I am using docker-compose setup of loki on my windows system and I want to change promtial configuration to access my windows log files. But it seams that docker not able to access outside path.

```
- job_name: test
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - test
    labels:
      job: test
      __path__: "F:/project/test/logs/*.log"

Answer:
promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.4.0
    volumes:
      - F:/project/test/src/logs:/test/logs
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml
    networks:
      - loki
```

Comment: That's right. Containers can't access files outside their own file system for security reasons. So you need to map F:\project\test\logs to a path in the container using a volume mapping and then use the path in the container for promtail.

Comment: Humm, finally able to solve as suggested I change docker-compose.yml file and mount using volumes.

Comment: Maybe @HansKilian can turn this comment into an answer so OP can approve it?